# Python returning SyntaxError while trying to reference CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a CS assignment I need to complete and one syntax error is stopping me from going forward.

I want to print out lines in a CSV that have the value Y in the second column, and if they do, take the first column value and put it in a dictionary. Right now, I want to make it just print the dictionary.

However, I have no idea why, but it is giving me a SyntaxError.

This is what I have so far:

```
import csv
d = {}
#Scan mandatory categories
with open('MandatoryFlags.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            line_count += 1
        else:
            if str(row[1]) = "Y":
                d["MCat{0}".format(line_count)] = row[0]
            else:
                continue
            line_count += 1
print(d)
```

I have not even the slightest clue why, but this is returned:

```
  File "C:/Users/Assoufi/PycharmProjects/ComputerScience/CSAssignment4.py", line 12
    if str(row[1]) = "Y":
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can I get some help?

Comment: No need to answer this folks, vote to close simple typos

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant `if str(row[1]) == "Y":`.

Comparison in Python is done with a double equals (`==`).

If I may intervene, your code would be much better off using `enumerate()` like so:

```
d = {}

with open('MandatoryFlags.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    iterator = enumerate(csv_reader)
    next(iterator)  # Skip first line
    for line_count, row in iterator:
        if str(row[1]) == "Y":
            d["MCat{0}".format(line_count)] = row[0]
```

Or even shorter:

```
with open('MandatoryFlags.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    iterator = enumerate(csv_reader)
    next(iterator)  # Skip first line
    d = {f"MCat{n}": row[0] for n, row in iterator if str(row[1]) == "Y"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a shot with the most obvious issue.  An if statement requires two equal signs.

Instead of:
`if str(row[1]) = "Y":`

Try this:
`if str(row[1]) == "Y":`

Note: I did not review the rest of the code... just addressing the syntax error.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is that you used one equal sign instead of two at

```
if str(row[1]) = "Y":
```

Comparison in python is done with two equal signs:

```
import csv
d = {}
#Scan mandatory categories
with open('MandatoryFlags.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            line_count += 1
        else:
            if str(row[1]) == "Y":
                d["MCat{0}".format(line_count)] = row[0]
            else:
                continue
            line_count += 1
print(d)
```